# django keeps creating new migrations even when model has not changed

Tags: django, migration

The following is my model:

```
class Biovariable(models.Model):
    bioid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    units = models.ForeignKey(unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Biovariable_data(models.Model):
    biovar = models.ForeignKey(Biovariable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    evdate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    evtime = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    linkedcustomer = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    linkeddoctor = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    linkedclinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            "biovar", "value", "evdate", "evtime", "linkedcustomer",
            "linkeddoctor", "linkedclinic"
        ]
```

Each time I run makemigrations, django keeps creating new migrations, and I cant understand why.

```
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'appointments':
appointments/migrations/0010_auto_20190310_2138.py
    - Add field dob to customer
    - Alter field biovar on biovariable_data
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, appointments, auth, clinic, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying appointments.0010_auto_20190310_2138... OK
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'appointments':
appointments/migrations/0011_auto_20190310_2139.py
    - Alter field biovar on biovariable_data
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'appointments':
appointments/migrations/0012_auto_20190310_2139.py
    - Alter field biovar on biovariable_data
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, appointments, auth, clinic, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying appointments.0011_auto_20190310_2139... OK
Applying appointments.0012_auto_20190310_2139... OK
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'appointments':
appointments/migrations/0013_auto_20190310_2140.py
    - Alter field biovar on biovariable_data
joel@hp:~/myappointments$
```

One of these migration files looks like this:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.3 on 2019-03-10 16:09
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('appointments', '0010_auto_20190310_2138'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='biovariable_data',
            name='biovar',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='appointments.Biovariable'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Are you change anything in anything like null, blank value?

Comment: This usually happens when you have a parameter value that is dynamic (the value changes, so python detects it as a “new” migration). Please show us the rest of your models.py

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but nothing in my model was dynamic. This occurred for me after changing the name of the model in question. (For reference it was a many to many through model which I renamed from "Enrollment" to "Registration").

Answering to provide a more explicit solution which was:

```py
# 1 - Roll back migrations
python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero>

# 2 - Delete the migration files

# 3 - Make a new migration
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and documented in similar questions, this is usually because of something dynamic in the model such as a datetime or set of choices that's coming up in an undetermined order.

The issue could also be related to a minor typo or change such as lower vs. upper case characters.  In my case, my FK's model initial migration had the name set to a lowercased word rather than the proper upper case name.  The referencing model was getting an alter field every time I ran `makemigrations`.  Fixing the FK model's initial migration file by simply capitalizing the name solved the problem:

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='sentence',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
```

to

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Sentence',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
```

Not sure how the lower case character got in there in the first place, though...

It might be a bit difficult to look through every migration file for something like this, however, so I'd recommend just removing all of your migration files, and doing a fresh `makemigrations` to start over from scratch.

If you'd rather not do this for some reason (migrations have already been synced to git, for example) you could move your migration files to a temporary location, run `makemigrations` and then see if a `git diff` shows anything inconsistent in your original and new initial migration files.  If you're able to find the issue, restore your original migration files and fix the problem there.